# DMA2D STM32F429

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, lcd, keil

Can any one help me to change the alpha value in my foreground? I have written a function to show my images by DMA2D. It is OK when I call my function and change the value, but when I use a `for` loop to change my foreground slowly it does not work; it doesn't put the new value which I assigned to it in the `for` loop.

My code is below. I want my image to fade away slowly.

```
for (i=0; i<=255; i++) {
  DMA2D_Show_Logo((uint32_t *)T10, (uint32_t *)(SDRAM_START_ADR + 2 * (800 * 120 + 230)), 340, 240, 255 - i, CM_RGB565);
  LTDC_ReloadConfig(LTDC_IMReload); 
  Delay_us(1000);
}
```

As you see the `uint8_t 255` is my alpha value, but it doesn't go through the loop. Are there any programming logic mistakes?
** When I configure a loop to count from 0 to 255, it is ok! but it won't show my logo for a loop to count from 255 to 0!

Here is my function:

```
void DMA2D_Show_Logo(uint32_t *src, uint32_t *dst, uint16_t w, uint16_t h, uint8_t Alpha, uint32_t CMode) {
  DMA2D_InitTypeDef DMA2D_InitStruct;
  DMA2D_FG_InitTypeDef DMA2D_FG_InitStruct;
  DMA2D_BG_InitTypeDef DMA2D_BG_InitStruct;
  DMA2D_DeInit(); 
  DMA2D_InitStruct.DMA2D_Mode = DMA2D_M2M_BLEND;       
  DMA2D_InitStruct.DMA2D_CMode = DMA2D_RGB565;      
  DMA2D_InitStruct.DMA2D_OutputGreen = 0x00;      
  DMA2D_InitStruct.DMA2D_OutputBlue = 0x00;     
  DMA2D_InitStruct.DMA2D_OutputRed = 0x00;                    
  DMA2D_InitStruct.DMA2D_OutputAlpha = 255;           
  DMA2D_InitStruct.DMA2D_OutputMemoryAdd = (uint32_t)dst; 
  DMA2D_InitStruct.DMA2D_OutputOffset = 800-w;              
  DMA2D_InitStruct.DMA2D_NumberOfLine = h;         
  DMA2D_InitStruct.DMA2D_PixelPerLine = w;
  DMA2D_FG_InitStruct.DMA2D_FGO = 0;
  DMA2D_FG_InitStruct.DMA2D_FGMA = (uint32_t)src;                                                    
  DMA2D_FG_InitStruct.DMA2D_FGCM = CMode;   
  DMA2D_FG_InitStruct.DMA2D_FGPFC_ALPHA_MODE = COMBINE_ALPHA_VALUE  ;
  DMA2D_FG_InitStruct.DMA2D_FGPFC_ALPHA_VALUE = (uint8_t) Alpha ;
  DMA2D_FG_InitStruct.DMA2D_FGC_BLUE = 0x00 ;
  DMA2D_FG_InitStruct.DMA2D_FGC_GREEN = 0;
  DMA2D_FG_InitStruct.DMA2D_FGC_RED = 0x00; 
  DMA2D_BG_InitStruct.DMA2D_BGO = 800 - w;
  DMA2D_BG_InitStruct.DMA2D_BGMA = (uint32_t)dst;                                                        
  DMA2D_BG_InitStruct.DMA2D_BGCM = CM_RGB565;
  DMA2D_BG_InitStruct.DMA2D_BGPFC_ALPHA_MODE = REPLACE_ALPHA_VALUE ;
  DMA2D_BG_InitStruct.DMA2D_BGPFC_ALPHA_VALUE = 255 ;   
  DMA2D_BG_InitStruct.DMA2D_BGC_BLUE = 0x00;
  DMA2D_BG_InitStruct.DMA2D_BGC_GREEN = 0;
  DMA2D_BG_InitStruct.DMA2D_BGC_RED = 0x00; 
  DMA2D_Init(&DMA2D_InitStruct);  
  DMA2D_FGConfig(&DMA2D_FG_InitStruct);
  DMA2D_BGConfig(&DMA2D_BG_InitStruct);

  /* Start Transfer */ 
  DMA2D_StartTransfer();  
  /* Wait for CTC Flag activation */
  while (DMA2D_GetFlagStatus(DMA2D_FLAG_TC) == RESET) {}    
}
```

I have the same problem to change a parameter in other libraries.

Comment: You have your foreground layer configured with `COMBINE_ALPHA_VALUE`.  Shouldn't it be `REPLACE_ALPHA_VALUE` instead?

Comment: I changed to REPLACE_ALPHA_VALUE but it does't make sense!!!

Comment: It does make sense. "COMBINE" meant to take the alpha value you give (from your `for` loop) and *combine* it with the alpha value that's already there - so the resulting alpha value is a *combination* of the old alpha and the new one. But that's not what you want. You want you new alpha to be used as-is - you want it to *replace* the old alpha

Comment: It's been a while since I last looked at that part of the DMA2D documentation, but I'm almost certain that you don't have to re-copy your entire logo in each iteration of the `for` loop. All you really need to do is change the alpha value applied to the entire foreground layer with a `DMA2D_FGConfig` call in the loop - you shouldn't need to reconfigure the background (`DMA2D_BGConfig`) or `DMA2D_StartTransfer` to update the image.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.. I have some questions, Can you explain why I should configure back and fore ground... I don't understand what background does...and I commented the background in my function and changed my alpha value to "replace", this time it showed my logo and again my logo but in smaller size back of my logo... and the back logo was fading...